# On a corrolary of Lucas theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3820), the author stated that we can use Lucas theorem to prove that 
$$\binom{ap^f+r}{m}\equiv \binom{r}{m}\ (\text{mod}\ p)$$

where $0\le r, m < p^f$, $a\ge 0$.

I don't know how to use Lucas theorem to deduce that.

My idea is follows

> Let $a=a_0+a_1p+...+a_wp^w$, $r=r_0+r_1p+...+r_up^u$, $m=m_0+m_1p+...+m_vp^v$ be the p-nary representation of $a, r, m$ respectively, then $ap^f+r=r_0+r_1p+...+r_up^u+a_0p^f+...+a_wp^{f+w}$.
>
> Applying Lucas theorem, we have 
>   $$ \binom{ap^f+r}{m}\equiv \binom{r_0}{m_0}\binom{r_1}{m_1}...\binom{r_v}{m_v}.\binom{r_{v+1}}{0}...\binom{r_u}{0}.\binom{a_0}{0}...\binom{a_w}{0}=\binom{r_0}{m_0}\binom{r_1}{m_1}...\binom{r_v}{m_v}$$
>
> But note that by Lucas theorem again, we have 
>   $$\binom{r}{m}\equiv \binom{r_0}{m_0}\binom{r_1}{m_1}...\binom{r_v}{m_v} \ (\text{mod}\ p)
> $$
>
> Therefore, $\binom{ap^f+r}{m}\equiv \binom{r}{m}\ (\text{mod}\ p)$

I see that it's too obvious. Am I wrong? If i'm wrong please point out my mistake and provide a proof using Lucas theorem.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why "too obvious"?  Obvious is a good thing, when it's true.

Comment: Looks okay to me; some things really are easy.

Comment: The idea looks fine, but I think the way you've written it assumes that $r \geq m$?

Comment: @MichaelHarrison If $r<m$ then $\binom{r}{m}=0$, which is quite nonsense, isnt it?

Comment: It looks from the way you stated the assumptions that it's a valid case to consider.  You're right that $\binom{r}{m} = 0$ in this case, but then you want to argue that the left side is also $0$ mod $p$.

Comment: @Arsenaler For example, it allows you to say things such as: $3$ divides $\binom{11}{4}$.  ($r=2$, $m=4$, $p=3$, $f=2$, $a=1$), This seems like a reasonable application of this result.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarrison, so in case $r<m$, what should I do?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarrison, but is there any other way to use Lucas theorem and prove this result?

Comment: @Arsenaler I think your proof is fine.  Atleast you wrote it out once, so now you see everything that cancels.  If $r<m$ then for some $t$, you'll have $m_t > r_t$, which makes $\binom{r_t}{m_t} = 0$, which makes the whole product $0$ (mod $p$).